# Android Studio or ADB.exe won't detect device

Tags: android, android-studio, device, usb-debugging

I have recently bought a HTC Nexus 9 tablet for the purpose of USB debugging in Android Studio. This process works on other computers at university but I cannot get it to work properly from my home system,which is what I require. I have tried every single suggestion I have came across online but none have actually worked.

Steps Tried:

- Downloading the latest google USB Driver
- Installing it through Android Studio and Manually in device manager
- Tried ADB Interface Driver and ADB Composite Interface Driver
- Configuring driver inf file by adding hardware ID's
- Ensuring usb debugging is enabled on the device
- Using different USB ports,3 different cables
- Tried connecting in PTP mode,MTP mode,charging only mode
- Rebooted device and computer
- Re installed android studio

No matter what I do,the device wont be shown in android studio or ADB.exe(under list all devices in terminal,also tried start and kill server). I am officially out of ideas,if anyone could figure this out I would be forever grateful!

I have attached some images of some of the things I have tried without success. Once driver has been installed it is listed as "Android Composite ADB Interface" or "Android ADB Interface". Operating system is Windows 7 64-bit

[Device on first plug in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ey3R.png)

[Picking a driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWH9K.png)

Comment: Download HTC PC Suite for windows ,install it and then give a try

Comment: Have you unlock the developer mode in the device, and allowed your `home` computer to communicate with it? (usually, click Build number 7 times, but this may vary by Android version)

Comment: @Bonatti Developer mode is definitely enabled/unlocked

Comment: What I meant was, does the device received the encrypted key, and allows the PC to communicate? Its best to explicitely state what you have already tried (the steps in your question), so that others may offer a different approach. Finally, can you communicate with any other device on your home computer?

Comment: @Bonatti The device does not receive the key,and other devices work fine on home PC

Answer (score 0):

Download HTC PC suite from following link ,install and give a try

http://pc2.software112.com/getfreesw/231109-1805719/htc-pc-suite-07.html

Comment: Unfortunately this does not detect the device either,just says no device connected

Answer (score 0):

I personally have had many issues with setting things up for Android. Things you should ensure you do include;

Ensure you obtain the appropriate packages in the SDK manager - for example, I wasn't able to make logcat work when debugging with my phone until I downloaded the files for my specific version of Android (so the API files for a Nexus 9).

I believe you may also have to download drivers for your actual phone to allow connection - you should be able to download this from the HTC website. This might be what you need, although I haven't checked it out, and I cant find where I downloaded my drivers from;

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2217396

In general, you want to download lots of things from the SDK manager as you'll need them anyway, so don't hold back on just downloading them.

Comment: No luck with those drivers for HTC devices,in the process of downloading a lot more from the SDK manager

Comment: Are you able to access stuff in the tablet from your computer at all (i.e. accessing the files inside it from your computer?)

Comment: also, make sure of specifically having the platform tools and SDK tools and the SDK build tools. Keep adding other stuff as well though

Comment: I can access the files on the tablet when USB debugging mode is not on and the driver is detected as "Nexus 9" under portable devices,it is only when i enable usb debugging mode that the drivers change and are detected as Android which is where i attempt to install the google usb driver which still does not work, I will keep adding the various SDK tools

Answer (score 0):

For those (like me) who is still concerned with this issue. You need to go to win+pause break ->Device Manager->Find "AdbInterface" with exclamation sign->Update driver->Search manually->Specify USB driver downloaded from SDK and enjoy: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\usb_driver